# How to distinguish event effects from seasonal influence

Tags: r, time-series, lme4-nlme

I am working on a study that investigates the effects of recurrent annual flooding on ammonia concentrations in a certain region. The flooding event occurs consistently on the same days each year. My challenge is to separate the impact of these flooding events from regular seasonal variations that might also influence ammonia levels. I want to ensure that the changes I attribute to flooding are not confounded with regular seasonal changes.

My dataset is structured as follows (simplified for clarity), covering multiple years with daily observations:

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="day")
set.seed(123) 
ammonia_concentration <- runif(length(date), min=0.5, max=2.0)
flooding_event <- as.Date(c("2017-06-03", "2018-06-03", "2019-06-03")) %in% date
df <- data.frame(date, ammonia_concentration, flooding_event)
```

Is there a way to statistically test the significance of the flooding events' impact on ammonia levels separate from the seasonal effects?
Any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant R packages and functions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because "occurs consistently on the same days each year" sounds exactly like a seasonal event, how could you hope to discriminate between flooding and seasonality?  Perhaps if significant floods occur at other times of the year you could exploit data from them, but you haven't told us enough about your problem even to speculate about such possibilities.